# Passing AJAX variables to rails controller

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using gmaps4rails in a javascript callback function to determine the user's location and then plot this location on a map. I then want to access this location info in the controller and use ruby geocoder to query for nearby events. According to firebug console I can see that the latitude, longitude co-ordinates are being posted but when i try to access these params in the controller it's not working - that is i'm not getting any errors but no events are being displayed on the map ( however if i type the user address directly into the controller code the nearby events are being displayed). See my code below. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Callback in events/index.html.erb**

```
 <% content_for :scripts do %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var lat;
    var lng;

Gmaps.map.geolocationSuccess = function(){
      if(Gmaps.map.callback){
        lng = Gmaps.map.userLocation.lng();
        lat = Gmaps.map.userLocation.lat();
        Gmaps.map.addMarkers([{
            "lng": lng,
            "lat": lat,
            "picture": "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markers/pink/blank.png",
            "width": "37",
            "height": "34"
        }]);

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'events/index',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "latitude=" + lat + "&longitude=" + lng,          
          });
      }
    };     

    </script>
    <% end %>
```

**Events Controller**

```
  def index
    @events = Event.near(params[:latitude], params[:longitude],2)
    @json = @events.to_gmaps4rails

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.js {render json: @events, content_type: 'text/json' }
   end
 end
```

Comment: Does your `index` actually respond to a `POST` request?  It's probably a `GET`, which you can verify by looking at `rake routes`.

Comment: Also, what are you seeing in the Rails logs?  Any `no route matches` errors?

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for the suggestions. I had a look at the log and it seems the issue is with Ruby Geocoder. Apparently the geocoding API is not responding fast enough. I increased the timeout limit in the geocoder configuration but Im still getting the same error.I'm sure what to do! Do you think there is any way around it?